# How to load the record page wise from database in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC application. 
I have around 8000 records in database.

I have used MVC.Grid to display these records.
My problem is,  I load all the 8000 records in controllers method. 
I want to fetch it page wise or some part of records, like 100 records each time...

How to do this ?

```
      public ActionResult Index(int? page, string searchContent = "")
        {

            ProductService productService = new ProductService();


            var pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            var pagesize = 15;

            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["loggedEmpId"]);
            CommonService.SetEmployeeId(id);

            ProductService ProductService = new ProductService();
            var productList = ProductService.GetProductInventory();

            LocationService locationservice = new LocationService();

            var loclist = locationservice.GetAll().Where(x => x.Type != LocationTypeDTO.HO).ToList();
            ViewBag.loc = loclist;
            ViewBag.SearchContent = searchContent;

            return View(productList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pagesize));

        }



   public IEnumerable<ProductDTO> GetProductInventory()
        {
            List<ProductDTO> ProductDTOList = new List<ProductDTO>();
            UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork();
            IEnumerable<Product> ProductList = uow.ProductRepo.GetInventoryList();
            foreach (Product product in ProductList)
            {
                ProductDTO productDTO = Transform.Product2DTO(product);
                ProductDTOList.Add(productDTO);
            }
            return ProductDTOList;
        }
```

Comment: use `.Take(100)` to get 100 records. Also take a look [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: how to use .Take(100) method ? and where ?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to fetch only first 100 record from database then you have do change in service method like -

```
var loclist = locationservice.GetAll().Where(x => x.Type != LocationTypeDTO.HO).Take(100).ToList();
```

Comment: Definitely the right answer. Do pagination IN THE SERVICE layer, not the controller action. 

If it's done in the controller action, then you're still having the database / network performance hit of fetching ALL records, when you want only 100. 

In most cases this is simply an Entity Framework expression, Lynq or SQL expression (or stored procedure) change.

Answer (score 0):

In 99% percent you shouldn't show all 8000 records.

You should use [pagination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination). You should get 100 record in the action and display it.

**update:**
You have very confusing and wrong code. 
You should use Take() and Skip() for your request.

I don't know what do `ToPagedList` method

Comment: Ya, I already used pagination but its in grid... I want to know how do I fetch record from DB pagewise... any example available ?